# How to keep QTextFrame/QTextBlock on one page?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

Is there a way to keep the content of a `QTextFrame` or `QTextBlock` together on the same page?

I don't want to insert a page break if there is still enough space for the content on the current page, but if not, all content should move together to the next page.

I know that there's `PageBreak_Auto`/`PageBreak_AlwaysBefore`/`PageBreak_AlwaysAfter`, but as far as I see `PageBreak_Auto` does split the content between pages and the other two always insert a page break before/after the segment no matter if there was enough space on the current page or not.